# Pass value Bean to Class then Class to JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I did initialize  my bean like below :

```
<bean id="propertyData" class="utils.PropertyDataFill" scope="application">
    <property name="current" value="${current}"/>
    <property name="name" value="${name}"/>
    <property name="isActiveU" value="${u}"/>
    <property name="isActiveG" value="${g}"/>
    <property name="isActiveM" value="${m}"/>
</bean>
```

I have created a PropertyDataFill Class using getter setter of  following 
variable :

```
private String current;
private String name;
private String isActiveU;
private String isActiveG;
private String isActiveM;
```

What I want is to pass this data to JSP :

```
<jsp:useBean id="propertyData" scope="application" class="utils.PropertyDataFill"/>  

<% 

  String m=propertyData.getIsActiveM();
  String u=propertyData.getIsActiveU(); 
  String g=propertyData.getIsActiveG(); 

%>
```

Where I am wrong,I am getting null value. ?
The way I am trying to do this is may be wrong .
Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: did your intialize works? i mean bean variable intialize?

Comment: May be not. How to check this ?? @atiqkhaled

Comment: `jsp:useBean` has nothing to do, nor knowns anything about beans in the spring context. You basically have 2 instances this way.

Comment: what should i do??

Comment: Bean initialization worked. I just checked it . How to pass from bean class to JSP.

Comment: @M.Deinum You are right about that. What should i do? Want Bean Class value in my JSP page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the value in ServletContext in your bean class:

```
 @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    private String a;
    public void setA(String a) {
       servletContext.setAttribute("a",a);
    }
```

Get this value in JSP using :

```
<%
String a=(String)getServletContext().getAttribute("a");
%>
```

Comment: Correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use Jsp:getProperty "<jsp:getProperty name="instanceOfBean" property="propertyName" />  " like 

    <jsp:getPropery name="propertyData" properyty="*"> <% 
    <%
      String m=propertyData.getIsActiveM();
      String u=propertyData.getIsActiveU(); 
      String g=propertyData.getIsActiveG(); 

    %>
```